# How can I use LZMA compression in react?

Tags: reactjs, string, npm, compression, lzma

I'm trying to compress strings in react and I want to know how can I import the LZMA compression library in react using NPM. Right now I'm working directly with the NPM but when I put this into my code `var my_lzma = require("lzma").LZMA();` it says that the lzma_worker.js is not found.